# Is init in Swift the same as a constructor in C#?

Tags: c#, swift

I'm a developer coming from C#. Is the init() method the same as a constructor in c#?

For example in C# this is how we would create an instance:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public void MyClass()
   {
      //set some properties
   }
}
...
// Call the constructor somewhere else
MyClass myInstance = new MyClass();
```

In Swift I was looking for an equivalent and I came across the init method. Is this correct to assume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is init in Swift the same as a constructor in C#?

Yes it is. As it is stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html):

> Initializers are called to create a new instance of a particular type.
>   In its simplest form, an initializer is like an instance method with
>   no parameters, written using the init keyword:

```
init() {
    // perform some initialization here
}
```